# Modal bootstrap não abre conforme link dinâmico

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Trago uma listagem em PHP/Mysql do qual abro em uma janela modal a descrição de um determinado produto. O código encontra-se da seguinte maneira:

Página listar-produtos.php

```
while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
  $listar = "<a href=\"ver-produtos.php?Key=".$jm->IdCodProdutos."\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary\">Ver currículo</a></div>";
}
```

**Modal**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">

           </div>
           <!-- /.modal-content -->
     </div>
     <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

**Página ver-produtos.php**

```
// teste
echo $_REQUEST['Key'];
```

A janela abre corretamente, porém é necessário atualizar a página da listagem de produtos para que pegue o outro Key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O modal mantém o conteúdo da primeira requisição, então a primeira que você abrir será permanente até que recarregue a página.

Para corrigir o problema crie um toggle alternativo que refaça o carregamento.

```
$(document).on('click', "[data-toggle='meumodal']", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).attr("data-target");
  content = $(this).attr("href");
  $(target+".modal .modal-content").load(content,function(){
     $(target).modal('show');
  });
});
```

E use nos seus links

```
while($jm = mysqli_fetch_object($sql)){
  $listar = "<a href=\"ver-produtos.php?Key=".$jm->IdCodProdutos."\" data-toggle=\"meumodal\" data-target=\"#myModal\" class=\"btn btn-xs btn-primary\">Ver currículo</a></div>";
}
```

Comment: Olá Kadu. Certo. Fiz as alterações, só que o link ver-produtos.php abre em uma nova aba e não no modal.

Comment: Opa @Jose.Marcos. Estas a utilizar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)? Alterou o PHP adicionando o atributo `data-toggle=\"meumodal\"` no _link_?

Comment: Atualizei o código, para uma versão melhor...

Comment: Perfeito Kadu. Obrigado pela ajuda.