# Passar varialvel para modal

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma página com uma tabela cujo o campo código é link que abre uma modal. Preciso que ao abrir a modal, mostre outra tabela, só que com os dados de acordo com o valor do campo(código) clicado.
Como faço pra receber dentro da modal o valor do campo escolhido ?

Alguém sabe como devo fazer ?

### Código:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover center-text" name="carrtab" id="carrtab"
       style="background-color: #ffffff;">
    <thead align="center">
    <tr class="danger">
        <th class="text-center">Data</th>
        <th class="text-center">Tipo</th>
        <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
        <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
        <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
        <th class="text-center">Link</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?

    $tipoentradalog = post('tipoentradalog');
    $usuario = post('usuario');
    $codcliente = post('codcliente');
    $datade = post('datade');
    $dataate = post('dataate');
    $codigo = post('codigo');

        $sql = "select
                    l.datacriacao,
                    tl.nome as tipo,
                    l.descricao,
                    cli.nome as cliente,
                    us.nome as usuario,
                    l.codigo
                    from log l
                    inner join cliente cli on cli.codcliente=l.codcliente
                    inner join usuario us on us.codusuario=l.codusuario
                    inner join empresa emp on emp.codempresa=l.codempresa
                    inner join tipoentradalog tl on tl.codtipoentradalog=l.codtipoentradalog
                    where cli.codempresa=$codempresa
                    and l.datacriacao between '$datade%' and '$dataate%' ";
        if($usuario != ""){
            $sql .= " and us.codusuario=$usuario ";
        }
        if($codcliente != "") {
            $sql .= " and cli.codcliente=$codcliente ";
        }
        if($tipoentradalog != "") {
            $sql .= " and tl.codtipoentradalog=$tipoentradalog ";
        }

        $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

            foreach($rst as &$row){
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center"><?=normalDate($row['datacriacao']);?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?=$row['tipo']?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?=$row['descricao']?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?=$row['cliente']?></td>
                    <td align="center"><?=$row['usuario']?></td>
                    <td align="center"><a class="link-target" role="link" data-toggle="modal" href="#modalContainer" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="modalContainer" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><?=$row['codigo']?></a></td>
                </tr>
            <?
                if($row['codigo'] != "")
                {
                    global $codigo;
                    $codigo = $row['codigo'];
                }
            }?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Extrato Rodízio</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <h4>Chat</h4>
                        <table name="tabrod" id="tabrod" class="table table-bordered table-hover center-text" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
                            <thead align="center">
                            <tr class="danger">
                                <th class="text-center">Data</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
                                <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <?
                            $sql = "select cli.codcliente, cli.nome, emp.nome as empresa from cliente cli
                                    inner join empresa emp on emp.codempresa=cli.codempresa
                                    where cli.codcliente=$codigo;";
                            $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

                            foreach ($rst as $row) {
                                ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><?= $row['codcliente']; ?></td>
                                    <td align="center"><?= $row['nome'] ?></td>
                                    <td align="center"><?= $row['empresa'] ?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?
                            }?>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Comment: Pra fazer isso o conteúdo do seu Modal deve ser externo, e você deve fazer algo semelhante a [esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67126/8493).

Comment: Oi Kadu, obrigada pela ajuda. Então... não rolou aqui no meu. Fiquei um pouco confusa porque não identifiquei no me código um valor correspondente a 'IdCodProdutos' no exemplo que vc me mostrou. Tem como vc só me explicar o que devo fazer ? Obrigada.

Comment: No seu caso acredito que seja a variável `$row['codigo']`, porém o seu código está um pouco confuso, não creio que está com uma boa lógica. E todo o código que está dentro do `modal-content` deve ser uma página separada, que deve ser enviado a variável `$row['codigo']` para que seja carregado o seu SQL com os dados que você quer.

Comment: Eu entendi essa parte de uma página separada para a modal... Vou tentar de novo. Obrigada

Comment: Donna adicionei uma resposta, dê uma lida nela e tente fazer como eu fiz. Como eu não testei pode ter algum erro, faça alguns testes. Qualquer coisa deixe um comentário na resposta. Outra coisa que notei no teu código, é que você usa a _short tag_ `<?`, só tome cuidado, pois alguns servidores tem elas desabilitadas, sempre dê preferência à `<?php`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na sua página de exibição faça assim:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover center-text" name="carrtab" id="carrtab"
   style="background-color: #ffffff;">
<thead align="center">
<tr class="danger">
    <th class="text-center">Data</th>
    <th class="text-center">Tipo</th>
    <th class="text-center">Descrição</th>
    <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
    <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
    <th class="text-center">Link</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?

    $tipoentradalog = post('tipoentradalog');
    $usuario = post('usuario');
    $codcliente = post('codcliente');
    $datade = post('datade');
    $dataate = post('dataate');
    $codigo = post('codigo');

    $sql = "SELECT
                l.datacriacao,
                tl.nome as tipo,
                l.descricao,
                cli.nome as cliente,
                us.nome as usuario,
                l.codigo
            FROM log l
                INNER JOIN cliente cli ON cli.codcliente=l.codcliente
                INNER JOIN usuario us ON us.codusuario=l.codusuario
                INNER JOIN empresa emp ON emp.codempresa=l.codempresa
                INNER JOIN tipoentradalog tl ON tl.codtipoentradalog=l.codtipoentradalog
            WHERE 
                cli.codempresa=$codempresa AND 
                l.datacriacao BETWEEN '$datade%' AND '$dataate%' ";
    if(!empty($usuario)
        $sql .= " and us.codusuario=$usuario ";

    if(!empty($codcliente))
        $sql .= " and cli.codcliente=$codcliente ";

    if(!empty($tipoentradalog))
        $sql .= " and tl.codtipoentradalog=$tipoentradalog ";


    $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

        foreach($rst as &$row){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><?=normalDate($row['datacriacao']);?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$row['tipo']?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$row['descricao']?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$row['cliente']?></td>
                <td align="center"><?=$row['usuario']?></td>
                <td align="center">
                    <a href="loadmodal.php?codigo=<?=$row['codigo']?>" data-toggle="meumodal" data-target="#modalContainer" class="link-target" role="link" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="modalContainer" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;"><?=$row['codigo']?></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
    <?php
            if(!empty($row['codigo'])) {
                global $codigo;
                $codigo = $row['codigo'];
            }
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalContainer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', "[data-toggle='meumodal']", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).attr("data-target");
  content = $(this).attr("href");
  $(target+".modal .modal-content").load(content,function(){
     $(target).modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

**Obs.:** Repare na linha da tabela, onde é montado o link, algumas alterações foram realizadas ali. Uma alteração que vale notar é o atributo `href` que agora tem o nome da página que será criada com o código logo abaixo (o target foi para o atributo `data-target`). Também foi adicionado um *script* tirado [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/67126/8493).

Agora crie um arquivo PHP que tenha conexão com seu banco de dados, como uma página totalmente independente. E coloque o seguinte código nela:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Extrato Rodízio</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <h4>Chat</h4>
    <?php
        if (!empty($_GET['codigo'])){
            $codigo = filter_var($codigo);
    ?>
    <table name="tabrod" id="tabrod" class="table table-bordered table-hover center-text" style="background-color: #ffffff;">
        <thead align="center">
        <tr class="danger">
            <th class="text-center">Data</th>
            <th class="text-center">Cliente</th>
            <th class="text-center">Usuario</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php

            $sql = "SELECT 
                      cli.codcliente, cli.nome, emp.nome as empresa 
                    FROM cliente cli
                       INNER JOIN empresa emp ON emp.codempresa=cli.codempresa
                    WHERE cli.codcliente=$codigo;";
            $rst = my_query($connR, $sql);

            foreach ($rst as $row) {
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center"><?= $row['codcliente']; ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?= $row['nome'] ?></td>
                <td align="center"><?= $row['empresa'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php 
        } else {
    ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
            <p>Oops! O cliente não foi encontrado.</p>
        </div>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Kadu... o link código passa o valor pra url da modal porém não abre nada. Coloquei um console.log na função js pra saber e vi que a página retornava só #modalContainer, porém no código não tem nenuma div com esse id. O que devo colocara data-target ? Obrigada

Comment: Oi @Donnathegirl, desculpe a marcação do modal estava errada. Já corrigi. O `data-target` é `ID` do modal.

Comment: Yay! Funcionou! Muuuuuito obrigada pela ajuda @KaduAmaral. Abraços.