# Passar variavel para um modal

Tags: php, javascript

Estou querendo pegar o id da tabela e carregar um modal com os dados.
É uma página cursos.php que pega os dados do banco, mas não exibe todos os campos, criei um botão que ao clicar ele abre em forma de modal mais detalhes do curso, e a página que contém o php é o loadmodal.php
Não está abrindo o modal para carregar os dados, como eu posso fazer? Esse é o código que eu fiz até agora...

```
<h4>Lista de cusos</h4>


        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover">

            <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th width="15%">Área</th>
                    <th width="20%">Curso</th>
                    <th width="20%">Período</th>
                    <th width="25%">Horário</th>
                    <th width="5%">CH </th>
                    <th width="8%">Valor</th>
                    <th width="1%"></th>
                    <th width="10%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php
                    if($q>0){
                        while($pegar=mysql_fetch_assoc($busca)){

                            echo'<tr>';
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['area'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['curso'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['dtinicio'].' a '.$pegar['dtfim'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['horario'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['ch'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$pegar['investimento'].'</td>');
                            echo'<td> <a href="loadmodal.php?id='.$pegar['id'].'" data-toggle="meumodal" data-target="#myModalLabel" class="link-target" role="link" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="modalContainer" style="text-decoration: none; color: black;">
                            <img src=imgs/plus.png alt=Cadastrar width=20 height=20 border=0 lowsrc=Detalhes  title=Detalhes /> </td>';
                            echo'<td><a href="inscricao/cadastra.php?id='.$pegar['id'].'"> <button id="btn-signup" type="submit" class="btn btn-info" >Inscreva-se</button></a></td>';
                            echo'</tr>';

                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        echo"Nenhum Registro Encontrado";
                    }
                ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>




<div class="modal fade" id="modalContainer" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
       <div class="modal-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', "[data-toggle='meumodal']", function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  target = $(this).attr("data-target");
  content = $(this).attr("href");
  $(target+".modal .modal-content").load(content,function(){
     $(target).modal('show');
  });
});
</script>
```

---

loadmodal.php

```
<!-- Modal -->

   <div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Cursos</h3>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="table table-hover">

            <thead> 
                <tr>

                    <th width="15%">Área</th>
                    <th width="20%">Curso</th>
                    <th width="20%">Período</th>
                    <th width="25%">Horário</th>
                    <th width="5%">CH </th>
                    <th width="6%">Valor</th>
                    <th width="1%"></th>
                    <th width="10%"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

                <?php
                            echo'<tr>';                        
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['area'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['curso'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['dtinicio'].' a '.$dados['dtfim'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['horario'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['ch'].'</td>');
                            echo utf8_encode('<td class="esq">'.$dados['investimento'].'</td>');
                            echo'</tr>';


                ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: @KaduAmaral vi em seu post e estou adaptando...

Comment: Bem vindo ao sopt. Primeiro, seria interessante você explicar o que está fazendo e o que pretende fazer com o código, e onde é que não está funcionando. Só jogar o código não ajuda a entender o problema. Clique em [edit] e complemente a pergunta com essas orientações.

Comment: Caso essa pergunta seja uma referencia a outra, também é interessante adicionar o link da outra pergunta nesta.

Comment: Achei essa resposta, mas nao estou conseguindo achar o meu erro...
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80035/passar-varialvel-para-modal

Comment: Dá uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/81050/abrir-m%C3%BAltiplas-modais-bootstrap/81095#81095).